# Use List Element When Sending Bash Command In Remote Server

Tags: list, tcl, expect

My expect script connects to several remote servers successfully and echos commands, but I can't manage to have it echo an item from a list.

For example, when sshing to `server1` I'd like to output to terminal `fruit:apple`
But `apple` is saved in `expect` while the `send` sends it to a local terminal where the list is not defined. Is it possible to send `expect` variable to bash?

In particular the lines relevant to this from the code:

```
set counter 0
set types {apple orange}
set var $types($counter)
send -- "echo 'fruit:$var'\r"
set $counter [expr $counter+1]
```

Full code:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
# ./sshlogin.exp uptime
#declare hosts array"
set hosts {server1 server2}
set types {apple orange}
# setting credentials
set user jack
set password welcome
set counter 0
foreach vm $hosts {
        set var $types($counter)
        set timeout -1
        # now ssh
        spawn ssh $user@$vm -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no
        match_max 100000 # Look for passwod prompt
        expect "*?assword:*"
        # Send password aka $password
        send -- "$password\r"
        # send blank line (\r) to make sure we get back to gui
        expect "$ "
        send -- "echo 'fruit:$var'\r"
       expect "$ " 
       send -- "exit\r"
       set $counter [expr $counter+1]
expect eof }
```

Comment: found a work around /solution by using foreach with both lists; works great now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong

```
set counter 0
set types {apple orange}
set var $types($counter)
```

Tcl has [**lists**](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl14.html) which are numerically indexed arrays, and [**arrays**](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl22.html) which are associative arrays (hashes).

You access elements of a **list** with, typically, the [`lindex`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/lindex.htm) command.
You access elements of an **array** with the `$arrname($key)` syntax

To address the immediate problem with those 3 lines: you want

```
set var [lindex $types $counter]
```

Your answer is the perfect way to iterate over 2 lists, pulling out elements with the same numeric index.

Running through the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) would be beneficial.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Glenn, I definitely plan on going over the tutorial later this evening.

Answer (score 1):

Added the second list to the foreach loop, and since both are of the same length it works great.

`foreach` looks like this now:

```
foreach vm $hosts fruit $types {....
```

This link contains an example:
http://wiki.tcl.tk/1018